# Data structure for a Website

Tags: data-structures, web

I'm very new to web development and until now I have relied on MYSQL to store any information that needed to be saved. I was wondering though, how I would go about implementing my own data structure for a website. All of my experience with data structures come from school or personal projects in which the data structure terminates after the program has ended.

I guess I'm wondering if my data structure has to run 24/7 on the server as a background process or if there is another way? Also, are there any quick pointers you can give me to point me in the right direction?

Sorry if this is a stupid/obvious question, I'm still in college and I haven't had the opportunity to take any sort of web development class yet.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your question is currently too broad. Do you want to have your website available 24/7? Does your website need constant access to this "data structure"? What data are you planning to store? How often does it change? How much data will be stored?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand exactly what you say with "Data-structure". Of course if your website needs to have a database in the back for make the service of the website itself, it has to be active and reachable 24/7.
For the structure...it depends of the project itslef, of course use primary key(s) foreign key and the name of the column with a common sense for each name (doesn't call one "name" and another "nome" for example).
If you wull be more specific I'm glad to help you.